# Hashing for dot products

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory, hashing

I've come across this problem that uses hashing to compute dot products (for non-negative vectors).

Suppose we are in $d$-dimensional space and $M$ will be our target for our hash. That is we have a universal hash family $\mathcal{H}$ from which a hash function $h : [d] \rightarrow [M]$ is chosen.

Then given a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ we compute a new vector $v' \in \mathbb{R}^M$ via:

$v'$ is an array of all $0$s of size $M$. Then:

for $i = 1$ to $d$:

$v'[h(i)] = v'[h(i)]  + v[i]$

return $v'$

We then compute $v' \cdot u'$ instead I suppose given $v, u$.

Examining the performance of this algorithm, I am meant to see that:

$\mathbb{E}_{h \leftarrow \mathcal{H}}[v' \cdot u'] \leq v \cdot u + \frac{1}{M}\|v\|_1 \|u\|_1$

How does one see this fact? Slightly lost here.

Comment: Here is some intuition: "grouping together" a few indices (i.e, $h(i_1)=h(i_2)=\dots=h(i_k)$) creates an inaccuracy: $v'_{h(i_1)}\cdot u'_{h(i_1)}=\sum_{p,l=1}^k v_{i_p}\cdot u_{i_l}=\left( \sum_{p=1}^k v_{i_p}\cdot u_{i_p} \right) + \left( \sum_{p\neq l}^k v_{i_p}\cdot u_{i_l}\right)$ and notice that the error term is almost proportional to the sum of $k$ elements from $v$ times the sum of $k$ elements from $u$. Now since the hashing is good, we expect that each group will contain $\frac{d}{M}$ elements, which in other words is $\frac{1}{M}$ of the number of elements in $v$ and $u$.

Comment: So the expected error should be around the sum of $\frac{1}{M}$ of the elements from $v$ times the same from $u$. In average we expect this value to be $\frac{1}{M}\cdot \|v\| _1 \cdot \| u \| _1$ as well